# transfer function discrete

Tags: transfer-function, diagram, z-transform

If \$f[n]\$ is the input and \$g[n]\$ is the output, how can I determine the transfer function of the diagram?
[image: Block diagram]

Comment: Start writing down the equations on each line. Then see what `g[n]` equals too in terms of `f[n]`.

Comment: Also use some properties of block diagrams and see if you can reduce each step, little by little. This looks like some type of FIR filter so look up the properties of that as well.

Comment: Thanks ! I found the next transfer function H(z) = \frac{1-(\alpha/2) z^{-1}}{1+(\alpha/5) z^{-1}}

Comment: What's the output of the \$\small z^{-1}\$ block?

Comment: is a time shift

Comment: Yes, but what signal comes out of it?

Answer (score 0):

Naming the intermediate signal as v[n], you can write two equations:
$$ f[n] - \frac{\alpha}{5} v[n-1]= v[n],  $$
$$ v[n] - \frac{\alpha}{2} v[n-1]= g[n].  $$

Then, you can solve this for \$v[n]\$ using the Z transform on the first equation and apply that on the second equation. With some rearranging, you sould find the transfer function \$\frac{G(z)}{F(z)}\$.